# unsigned char array as key in a map (STL - C++)

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

There are some posts related to this, but I need to clarify something.
I have a structure in my program, and one of its fields is a fixed-size array (16). This is a reduced example of the mentioned structure:

```
my_struct{
     unsigned char my_field[16];
     ....
     // some more fields here
};
```

I want to use this field as a key for a map, and here is my question.
- Is there a way to use a map like

```
map<unsigned char[16], some_defined_structure>
```

? Otherwise, which would be the best way to somehow copy this char array to fit an array or vector structure to insert in the map afterwards?

Comment: If you change it to `std::array<unsigned char, 16>` this is straight forward.

Comment: Do you want the key comparison to always include all 16 unsigned chars (if so, then `std::array` is good), or is there some delimiter in there? (for the latter you could e.g. use `std::array` and a custom comparison function, or extract the relevant characters into a `std::string`)

Comment: @Simple ok then, and how is the best way to copy my_struct.my_field into the array? (I can't modify the original structure, so it needs to stay as unsigned char[16]). Any speed issues with this copy process?

Answer (score 7):

`unsigned char[16]` is not a suitable  type for key map. it does not meet the requirements 
 But `std::array<unsigned char,16>` does.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought... In that case, as I can't change the original structure, which is the best and fastest way to copy my_struct.my_field into a std::array<unsigned char, 16> variable?

Comment: @estradjs use `std::copy(std::begin(my_obj.my_field), std::end(my_object.my_field), x.begin())` (where `x` is a `std::array<unsigned char, 16>`) and then copy `x` into the `map`.

Comment: @Davidbrcz why didn't you specify what requirements it doesn't meet?

Comment: I don't really know, arrays are a bit weird. On gcc `#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
// using mykey_t = std::array<unsigned char,16>;
using mykey_t = unsigned char[16];
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  mykey_t t1{'p','i','p','o','1'};
  std::map<mykey_t, std::string> m;
  m[t1]="a";
  std::cout << m[t1] << "\n";
  return 0;
}`  fails to compile with `error: array used as initializer` and a big stack of template.